# J8583 project for parsing/creating iso8583 financial messages

Tags: iso8583, j8583

I'am currently looking for an api for parsing/creating iso8583. iso8583 is a barbarian iso norm of raw string message.

I have found the j8583 project, http://j8583.sourceforge.net/index.html, but i can't found easy code example to parse a message.

Do you know good examples using this api ? or using another api ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I need to reorganize/improve the docs?

The concept is fairly simple: Create a `MessageFactory`, configure it (the simplest way is via [XML config file](http://j8583.sourceforge.net/xmlconf.html)) and use that to parse messages with the `parseMessage` method, which receives a byte array.

The library includes a [simple message parser](https://bitbucket.org/chochos/j8583/src/master/src/main/java/com/solab/iso8583/util/SimpleParser.java) which you can look at to get an idea. The test suite can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for the project that you can clone
https://bitbucket.org/chochos/j8583/src/master/

here is the XML Configuration Guide
http://j8583.sourceforge.net/xmlconf.html

All from the same person and framework

Comment: jpos is another popular framework but it's paid vs this one that is a free open source.